# The difference between one pot synthetic method and one step reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, terminology

I often read in the papers of organic synthesis that the reactions can be carried out in one-pot method, and the others can be realized in one-step. I want to know the difference between **one pot** and **one step** in organic synthesis.

Answer (score 5):

"One step" refers to a process that produces the desired product by running a single reaction--especially in a situation where there are alternative pathways to the same product involving two or more reactions in a sequence.

"One pot" refers to a process involving a series of distinct reactions carried out sequentially and in a single reaction vessel to produce the desired product without isolating and purifying the intermediates after each step.